# Using STM32 as USB host to communicate with TTL

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-hostcontroller

everyone!
I'm trying to connect a TTL module on the CP210X chip to the STM32F401CDU6.

I have attempted to set up the STM as a USB Device Virtual Port Com, but it hasn't worked. I also tried setting up the STM as a USB HOST Virtual Port Com (using an example from this site 
[USB CDC Device and HOST in STM32](https://controllerstech.com/usb-cdc-device-and-host-in-stm32/)), but my STM doesn't recognize the TTL as a device and stops trying to send information.

Has anyone tried to implement something similar? If so, please share some examples or insights into what might be configured incorrectly during operation.

Comment: The STM32 has its own USART so you can just use that directly instead of sending USB packets to an CP210X and using it to convert those signals to TTL serial.  But if you really want to proceed with this project, you'll probably have to give more details, like how you are connecting the two devices and the exact error messages you're getting.  Also, what CP210x driver are you running on the STM32?  It's not a CDC device.

Comment: Yes, i used the CP210x a lot in recent projects. It works pretty strait forward: connect it to one of the U(S)ARTs of the MCU, do not forget to "flip" the Rx and Tx lines, plug it in to a PC and on Windows it works pretty well with the generic Virtual COM-Port drivers. So what you are trying to do is definitively feasible. Eventually you make you first tries with an standalone CP210x and e.g. a Bluepill? There you can change the wiring if necessary. Also keep in mind that USB traces need a certain impedance if they are longer. And check if your MCU if it has internal Pullup Resistors for USB.